# TransactionScope and SQL Transaction

Tags: c#

Please let me know..
 Can I use TransactionScope and SQL Transaction (Begin trans and Commit trans) at the same time.

Thanks,

Comment: did you try it? what happened?

Comment: There's no need to really. It's either one or the other. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270981/refactoring-ado-net-sqltransaction-vs-transactionscope

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it is not recommended. Transactions are great, but they can lead to subtle concurrency problems (contention, deadlocks, and alike ...) that are hard to debug, so you should try to minimize the code inside transactions and manage them very carefully. If sometimes it's hard to people do it using a single technology, imagine using two...